# SQL Server access and usage log

Tags: sql-server

ANY IDEA ?
I have Sql Server Enterprise 64 need to find:

1. The last time the SQL Server DB have been accessed (time)
2. Detailed information (the inventory) of all applications and/or users accessing the DB.

**Explanation:** I am doing an inventory of all my databases (around 120) which would help me decide whether to keep the DB  and that will help me a decision about: If the DB should be kept or consolidate it with another one.

I have been working with thise Scripts below but they are limited 
1 not working on 2000-05. I need more details like program name, statut, hostname, userinfo ... 
2-Need last used info 
May be both needed to be combined and refined.

**Script 1**

```
WITH last_query_by_db (dbid, Last_query) 

AS (select dbid, max(last_execution_time) 'Last_query'

from sys.dm_exec_query_stats 
cross apply 
sys.dm_exec_sql_text(plan_handle)
group by
dbid
)

select d.name, Last_query

from 
sys.databases d
left outer join
last_query_by_db q on q.dbid = d.database_id

where d.name not in ('master','msdb','model','tempdb')
order by 1
```

**Script 2**

```
SELECT HOSTNAME, PROGRAM_NAME, STATUS, SPID 


FROM    MASTER..SYSPROCESSES 

WHERE DBID= DB_ID('TestDB')

                AND SPID != @@SPID
```

Answer (score 0):

You can enable **Login Auditing** in SQL Server Management Studio. After that, you can see the logs like this:

1. In Object Explorer, expand a server, expand Management, and then expand SQL Server Logs.
2. Right-click a log and click View SQL Server Log.

Source: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187109%28v=SQL.100%29.aspx)

To check for the application name, use `SELECT APP_NAME()`. ([Source](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189770.aspx))

Also, there is an Activity Monitor in SQL Server that can provide valuable information:

[image]

Comment: Enabling login auditing will not give you the information about the calling application, AFAIK.

Comment: Well, the application logs in with an account. This info can be found.

Comment: Don't understand, how would you use APP_NAME() function with the Activity monitor or SQL Server error log?

Comment: will that be able to provide the info needed for the 120+ database?

Answer (score 0):

Implement an audit session (enterprise ed only) or xevents session (which version are you on?) or logon trigger.

Here's how to implement a logon trigger:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb326598.aspx

Comment: not talking about now in the future, talking about pass activities

Comment: Well, I'm afraid you can't. You have to set up logging beforehand.

Comment: is it possible to query it?

Comment: No, by default SQL Server doesn't save info about succesful logins

Comment: Yep it does. I have been working with this query below but it limited 1 not working on 2000-05. 2- I need more details like program name, statut, hostname...    
WITH last_query_by_db (dbid, Last_query) AS (
select
dbid, max(last_execution_time) 'Last_query'
from
sys.dm_exec_query_stats 
cross apply 
sys.dm_exec_sql_text(plan_handle)
group by
dbid
)
select
d.name, Last_query
from 
sys.databases d
left outer join
last_query_by_db q on q.dbid = d.database_id
where
d.name not in ('master','msdb','model','tempdb')
order by
1

Comment: OK, it's something else from what you've asked

Comment: ok sorry for that. but Can u understand now? or still confused

Comment: Problem with this query is that it's about accessing data, not about logins; not everything is cached; and cache is volatile, not only when you restart the service, but dynamically cleared as needed. It's an informational query, but not fit for an audit.

Comment: are you saying that the DB log can't be query or give us an history?

Comment: I'm saying that the information you're after in not persisted in the database by default. Querying the plan cache is unreliable, because the plan cache is dynamically managed.

Comment: If a trigger have to be implemented that will require to go to each individual server and implemented it. sound like...   I beleive can be done with script. but how still looking

Comment: I have also used this Script but its also limited but the output.    SELECT HOSTNAME,

   PROGRAM_NAME,
 
                STATUS,
 
                 SPID 

FROM    MASTER..SYSPROCESSES 

WHERE  SPID != @@SPID

Comment: sysprocesses view shows only active sessions, it's even less useful. To execute a script on multiple servers, use central management server feature: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb934126%28v=sql.100%29.aspx

Comment: i already have that setup but just looking for the script to run againt the servers

Comment: Here's an article that demonstrates how to use logon trigger to do almost exactly what you want: http://www.gethynellis.com/2011/08/audit-sql-logins.html